# How to express the statement mathematically?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group of order $n$. If $G$ is not cyclic, how can we express $G$?

**MY TRY**: Since $G$ is finite abelian, so $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}\times \mathbb Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}} \times \cdots\times \mathbb Z_{p_k^{\alpha_k}}$ where $p_i$ are primes and $\alpha_i\ge 1$  $\to (1)$.

Now we have been given that $G$ is not cyclic, so $G$ must have more than 1 factor in its decomposition.

Also the factors cannot be be coprime, i.e. if $G$ is a group of order $18$, then $G$ cannot have factors $\mathbb Z_9$  and $\mathbb Z_3$ in its decomposition.

However, I am unable to express this fact mathematically. Can someone please help me to express this fact mathematically by placing restrictions on the  indices of the factors of the decomposition given in Equation 1.

Please help me out.

Comment: I think you've expressed everything adequately.

Comment: I think in your example, though, you meant to say $G$ cannot have factors $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in its decomposition since $9$ and $2$ are coprime. The factors $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$, on the other hand, would be OK since $6$ and $3$ are not coprime.

Comment: @fleablood; i have expressed it in language, wont i need to express it mathematically as the question demands?

Comment: English is fine for discussing mathematics. If you want to use symbols only, you could say $\exists i,j (i\ne j) \land (p_i=p_j)$.